# Fechar form sem destruir C# visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou utilizando um form em minha aplicação que precisa ser carregado rapidamente, porém quando eu fecho esse form ele caba demorando sempre para carregar, existe uma forma de eu fechar o form mas ele não recarregar toda vez que eu abrir?

Dessa forma que eu fecho o form:

```
private void pbFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: isso não é nada bom, você teria que mantê-lo em memória declarando uma variável no form principal por exemplo e ao inves de fechar, ficar escondendo/mostrando o mesmo, imagina fazer isso com todos os forms da aplicação ?! Certamente há como melhorar o carregamento do form, mas pra isso você tem que mostrar o código dele, principalmente do construtor e do evento load, e das funções que são executadas dentro desses

Comment: Traduza e leia isso: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885041/how-to-load-a-winforms-app-quickly"> Ler </a> Isso provavelmente irá ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode alterar o comportamento do botao fechar, fazendo com que ele apenas oculte o form, se você usar o código abaixo no evento FormClosing do teu form, ele será apenas ocultado do usuário, mas permanecera aberto (consumindo recursos, é claro).

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
}
```

Para mostrar novamente, basta usar o método Show() no evento do botão (ou outro controle) que chame o form.

Creio que a solução ideal seria otimizar o carregamento do form, para poder fechá-lo normalmente, consumindo menos recursos do sistema.